# Creating a new DateTime object in PHP does not work

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following piece of code. I've recorded the output as well:

```
function convertGeneralAvailabilityTime($date,$from_timezone,$from_timebegin, $from_time$
{
echo "$date,$from_timezone,$from_timebegin, $from_timeend, $to_timezone"; 
// 2010-09-19,America/New_York,07:45:00, 08:00:00, America/Los_Angeles

$tz1 = new DateTimezone($from_timezone);

$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date $from_timebegin", $tz1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date $from_timeend", $tz1);

echo "$date $from_timebegin";
// 2010-09-19 07:45:00
echo "$date $from_timeend";
// 2010-09-19 08:00:00
var_export($tz1);
//DateTimeZone::__set_state(array(
//))
var_export($datetime1);
//DateTime::__set_state(array(
//))
```

SOmething is wrong with my php's DateTime() funciton - but I cannot fathom what! I'm using PHP 5.2.14 on this server.

---

Edit 1: Sorry, misinterpreted some PHP output - corrected it above

---

Edit 2: I had the following test file which gave the exactly output as below

```
<?php
$date = '2010-09-19';
$from_timezone = 'America/New_York';
$from_timebegin = '07:45:00';
$from_timeend = '08:00:00';
$to_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'; // Trimmed 2010-09-19 07:45:002010-09-19

$tz1 = new DateTimezone($from_timezone);

$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date $from_timebegin", $tz1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date $from_timeend", $tz1);

echo "$date $from_timebegin".PHP_EOL;
echo "$date $from_timeend".PHP_EOL;
var_dump($tz1);
var_dump($datetime1);

?>
```

Output:

```
jailshell-3.2$ php dttest.php
2010-09-19 07:45:00
2010-09-19 08:00:00
object(DateTimeZone)#1 (0) {
}
object(DateTime)#2 (0) {
}
```

---

Edit 3 - if it helps, my phpinfo shows this as well

```
date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2010.12
Timezone Database   external
Default timezone    America/Chicago
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplified and ran your code. This is the output:

```
php > $date = '2010-09-19';
php > $from_timezone = 'America/New_York';
php > $from_timebegin = '07:45:00';
php > $from_timeend = '08:00:00';
php > $to_timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles'; // Trimmed 2010-09-19 07:45:002010-09-19 08:00:00
php > 
php > $tz1 = new DateTimezone($from_timezone);
php > 
php > $datetime1 = new DateTime("$date $from_timebegin", $tz1);
php > $datetime2 = new DateTime("$date $from_timeend", $tz1);
php > 
php > echo "$date $from_timebegin".PHP_EOL;
2010-09-19 07:45:00
php > echo "$date $from_timeend".PHP_EOL;
2010-09-19 08:00:00
php > var_dump($tz1);
object(DateTimeZone)#1 (0) {
}
php > var_dump($datetime1);
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(19) "2010-09-19 07:45:00"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
```

I don't see a problem.

Your echo at the top contains junk at the end (after the timezone)

```
echo "$date,
      $from_timezone,
      $from_timebegin, 
      $from_timeend, 
      $to_timezone"
;

// 2010-09-19,
// America/New_York,
// 07:45:00, 
// 08:00:00, 
// America/Los_Angeles2010-09-19 07:45:002010-09-19 08:00:00
```

What's all the extra stuff at the end?

Comment: My var_dump($datetime1); gives exactly 'DateTime::__set_state(array(
))'

Comment: Hey Mike - any thoughts on why I'm not getting any output for $datetime1?

Answer (score 1):

Declare your default timezone before creating the DateTime object eg.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$tz1 = new DateTimezone($from_timezone);
$datetime1 = new DateTime("$date $from_timebegin", $tz1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime("$date $from_timeend", $tz1);
```

Or declare it in your php.ini files with date.timezone = "America/New_York"

Answer (score -3):

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($date $from_timebegin, $tz1);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($date $from_timeend, $tz1);

echo $date $from_timebegin;

echo $date $from_timeend;
```